# UITextView font Issue in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, uitextfield

If any string assigned to UITextView and string contain "\n" then UITextView font changes randomly. means font size changing.

This issue occurring me on only iOS 6. same code working on iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

UITextfield is intended to be used for single line text, if you want multi-line, use UITextview.

Comment: Sorry Muhammad typo mistake Issue occurring me on UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you have `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` set to YES on your `UITextField`.

Comment: Sorry,typo mistake Issue occurring me on UITextView